# Directory users update clearing fields not included in resource

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, google-apis-explorer

Google's documentation states that Users.update will only update fields included in the userResource object.  https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/update

In my script, I am able to submit updates successfully, but when I do, fields not specified are cleared out.  Here's an example:

Original user resource:

```
{
    orgUnitPath=/,
    ...
    "organizations": [
                    {
                      "name": "John",
                      "title": "developer",
                      "primary": true,
                      "department": "IT",
                      "location": "CA",
                      "description": "fulltime_employee",
                      "domain": "acme.com",
                      "costCenter": "123456"
                    }]
}
```

I want to update just one of the fields, title = 'Sr. Developer'.  When I submit the partial userResource with Users.update, the rest of the fields within the array element are cleared even though they were not submitted.

Submitted userResource

```
{
    orgUnitPath=/,
    ...
    "organizations": [
                    {
                      "title": "sr. developer"
                    }]
}
```

Updated user

```
{
    orgUnitPath=/,
    ...
    "organizations": [
                    {
                      "name": "",
                      "title": "sr. developer",
                      "primary": true,
                      "department": "",
                      "location": "",
                      "description": "",
                      "domain": "",
                      "costCenter": ""
                    }]
}
```

Is there a way to correct this, or do I need to load each field within the element and submit them all with only the changed fields updated?

Comment: I think it's part of the request body to also include all of the given parameter that you want to use with the field you want to update.

Comment: Not sure I follow your comment.  If you are required to supply all the previously populated fields, then you are no longer doing a patch, its a full profile update.